# Aggregate copublications associated with a primary publication

Tags: r, dplyr

Each primary_citation may have multiple copublications.  I would like to aggregate citation_id's associated with each primary citation. The following code works, but creates duplicate rows that must subsequently be removed. I'm looking for a way to avoid creating duplicate rows.

```
  dat %>% 
  group_by(primary_citation) %>% 
  mutate(copublications = paste0(citation_id, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-citation_id)

 dat <- structure(list(primary_citation = c("29967037", "32439388", "32439388", 
"28475431", "29967037", "29703800", "29967037", "23899372", "28125624", 
"35304745", "12057549", "12057549", "12057549", "12057549", "12057549"
), citation_id = c("34176288", "34470135", "149786406", "32119129", 
"32517785", "31121137", "L621236193", "28125624", "23899372", 
"31641005", "19366459", "17166220", "17166221", "16411990", "15113445"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: I find your above works if `group_by(citation_id)` ; desired output would be useful.

Comment: Output is as desired, but retains duplicate rows, which must be removed with distinct()

Comment: There are no duplicated rows when running the code with `group_by(citation_id)`?

Comment: The slower unique.data.frame(dat2), post process with ` group_by(citation_id)` doesn't discern any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lmk if is that what you needs:

```
dat %>%
        group_by(primary_citation) %>%
        mutate(N = paste0("copublication_",row_number())) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        pivot_wider(
                id_cols = primary_citation,
                names_from = N,
                values_from =  !c(primary_citation, N),
                values_fill = NA)
```

[image: Output]